# Deleting One Side of A Many-to-many Relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to have a many-to-many relationship in Grails 1.3.7 using the example given in the section "5.2.1.3Many-to-many". Here are the domains:

```
class Author {

String name

static mapping = {
    table 'authorx'
}

static hasMany = {
    books: Book
}
}

class Book {

String name

static mapping = {
    table 'bookx'
}

static hasMany = {
    authors: Author
}

static belongsTo = [Author]
}
```

The following lines don't work on either of these domains:

```
author.books
book.authors
```

Also, the table authorx_bookx that is supposed to be the junction table is not created in the database.

Comment: Paste your domain classes - that will make it easier for us to understand.

Try this 
meeting.participants.each {it.removeFromMetting(meeting)}
meeting.participants.clear()
meeting.save(flush:true)

Comment: I just switched to the example given in the Grails documentation. Hopefully that is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using { and } instead of [ and ] in one of the domains.